# How to Make rank per year and term on mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have data on table my database (MySQL)

```
SELECT * FROM `student_result_group`
```

Result

[image]

I try it :

```
SELECT year, term, grade_id, student_id, total_exam1, total_exam2, total,
       FIND_IN_SET( total, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total ORDER BY total DESC ) FROM student_result_group)) AS rank
from student_result_group
GROUP BY year, term, grade_id, student_id
```

and I get result like this :

[image]

I want this result:

[image]

Which query should I write to get rank per term and year?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks sir. i has been edit my title question.

Comment: Add your expected output

Comment: @1000111 i thanks sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this query :

```
    select
    s1.year, 
    s1.term, 
    s1.student_id, 
    s1.grade_id, 
    s1.total_exam1, 
    s1.total_exam2, 
    s1.total,
    count(s2.total)+1 AS rank
from
    student_result_group s1 LEFT JOIN student_result_group s2
    ON s1.grade_id = s2.grade_id AND s1.student_id != s2.student_id AND s1.term = s2.term AND s1.year = s2.year AND s1.total <= s2.total
GROUP by
    s1.student_id,
    s1.year,
    s1.term,
    s1.grade_id
ORDER BY
    s1.year, s1.term, s1.total, s1.student_id
```